# How To Change Color Using CSS

Tags: html, css

how do I change the colour using CSS?

```css
 .container .input-group .opt-group   { 
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%; 
     border: 3px solid #ece5e5; 
     padding: 15px 20px; 
     font-size: 1rem; 
     border-radius: 30px; 
     background: transparent; 
     outline: none; 
     transition: .3s; 

}
```

```html
 <html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="input-group">
        <select class="opt-group" name="gender" id="gender" required type="">
          <option  disabled selected required value="">Choose Your Gender</option>  
          <option value="male">Male</option>
          <option value="female"> Female</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
        </select> 
      </div> 
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

After I applied CSS, it wouldn't change. What's the problem? Please give me a solution, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific action that changes the color? Like maybe when you click on a radio button? And what color will you be changing text? background?

Answer (score 0):

change color of what?
if text color is what you want then

```
color: red
```

add this to your css

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the background color of the container you can use below

background: blue; or background-color:blue;

If you want to change text color

color: green ;